# Simplifying pre-calc

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing my homework and I'm stuck on this problem:
$$ \frac{\frac 1 {\sqrt{a}} + \frac {\sqrt{a}} 2}{\frac 1 {\sqrt{a}} - \frac {\sqrt{a}} 2} $$ 
I tried playing around with the powers, but failed pretty hard.

Comment: Multiply by
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt a} + \frac{\sqrt a}{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt a} + \frac{\sqrt a}{2}}$$

Comment: Try to add and subtract fractions in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand by $2\sqrt{a}$ and your'e done.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply above and below by $\sqrt{a}$ to get $\frac{1+ \frac{a}{2}}{1- \frac{a}{2}} = \frac{2+a}{2-a}$.